# How to bind a ListView's/CollectionView's DataTemplate to a ViewModel Property

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, data-binding, uicollectionview, datatemplate

I am building a Xamarin Forms controls library for internal use and I am attempting to define a DataTemplate as a bindable property that gets passed and set to a CollectionView via a ViewModel. When I do this I get a NRE deep within the Xamarin Forms unmanaged code and I get no specifics on that is causing the NRE within the caught exception. So it makes me wonder if this is even possible to do. All the examples I have found online all set the ItemTemplate directly, never is it a bound property. So, is this a doable thing?

This is where the exception occurs in the Xamarin.Forms code

```
        // Set the binding context _before_ we create the renderer; that way, it's available during OnElementChanged
        view.BindingContext = bindingContext;
```

The property does seem to be a bindable property so I would think this should work without issues.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty;
```

Collection View...

```
            <CollectionView Grid.Row="3"
                        Margin="16,0,16,16"
                        ItemTemplate="{Binding ItemTemplate}" <--- this is what I am trying to make work
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                        SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectedItemChanged}"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" />
```

View Model...

```
    private DataTemplate _itemTemplate;
    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _itemTemplate, value);
        }
    }

    ...

    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            var grid = new Grid();

            var nameLabel = new Label { FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold };
            var ageLabel = new Label();
            var locationLabel = new Label { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End };

            nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");
            ageLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Sybtitle");
            locationLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");

            grid.Children.Add(nameLabel);
            grid.Children.Add(ageLabel, 1, 0);
            grid.Children.Add(locationLabel, 2, 0);

            return new ViewCell { View = grid };

        });
```

List Item Model...

```
    public class ListPickerListItem {

    public ListPickerListItem(string title, string subtitle = "", string icon = "", string image = "")
    {
        Title = title;
        Subtitle = subtitle;
        Icon = icon;
        Image = image;
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    // prioritize the Image over the Icon since the Image has a default placeholder
    public bool IsIconVisible { get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Icon) == false && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Image); } }
    public bool IsImageVisible { get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Image) == false; } }

}
```

Exception stack...

```
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.TemplatedCell.Bind (Xamarin.Forms.DataTemplate template, System.Object bindingContext, Xamarin.Forms.ItemsView itemsView) [0x00068] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\CollectionView\TemplatedCell.cs:117 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ItemsViewController`1[TItemsView].UpdateTemplatedCell (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.TemplatedCell cell, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x0007b] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\CollectionView\ItemsViewController.cs:262 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ItemsViewController`1[TItemsView].CreateMeasurementCell (Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x0007b] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\CollectionView\ItemsViewController.cs:587 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ItemsViewController`1[TItemsView].GetPrototype () [0x0005d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\CollectionView\ItemsViewController.cs:362 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ItemsViewLayout.DetermineCellSize () [0x00060] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\CollectionView\ItemsViewLayout.cs:211 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewLayout.ConstrainTo (CoreGraphics.CGSize size) [0x0001e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\CollectionView\ListViewLayout.cs:16 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ItemsViewLayout.SetInitialConstraints (CoreGraphics.CGSize size) [0x00007] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\CollectionView\ItemsViewLayout.cs:111 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ItemsViewController`1[TItemsView].EnsureLayoutInitialized () [0x00044] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\CollectionView\ItemsViewController.cs:192 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ItemsViewController`1[TItemsView].ViewDidLoad () [0x00035] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\CollectionView\ItemsViewController.cs:148 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper(intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIViewController.get_View () [0x0002a] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:3265 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ItemsViewRenderer`2[TItemsView,TViewController].SetUpNewElement (TItemsView newElement) [0x00022] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\CollectionView\ItemsViewRenderer.cs:102 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.StructuredItemsViewRenderer`2[TItemsView,TViewController].SetUpNewElement (TItemsView newElement) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\CollectionView\StructuredItemsViewRenderer.cs:41 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.SelectableItemsViewRenderer`2[TItemsView,TViewController].SetUpNewElement (TItemsView newElement) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\CollectionView\SelectableItemsViewRenderer.cs:34 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ItemsViewRenderer`2[TItemsView,TViewController].OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e) [0x0000c] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\CollectionView\ItemsViewRenderer.cs:36 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) [0x00172] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:296 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:158 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00032] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:240 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view) [0x0003e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:115 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x0001e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:49 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) [0x0012e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:283 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:158 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00032] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:240 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view) [0x0003e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:115 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x0001e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:49 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) [0x0012e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:283 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:158 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00032] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:240 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view) [0x0003e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:115 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x0001e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:49 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer.ViewDidLoad () [0x0008f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\PageRenderer.cs:251 
  at Rg.Plugins.Popup.IOS.Renderers.PopupPageRenderer.ViewDidLoad () [0x00000] in Z:\Documents\OpenSource\Rg.Plugins.Popup\Rg.Plugins.Popup\Platforms\Ios\Renderers\PopupPageRenderer.cs:74 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper(intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIViewController.get_View () [0x0002a] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:3265 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer.get_NativeView () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\PageRenderer.cs:103 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x0003d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\PageRenderer.cs:119 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00032] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:240 
  at Rg.Plugins.Popup.IOS.Extensions.PlatformExtension.GetOrCreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement bindable) [0x0000a] in Z:\Documents\OpenSource\Rg.Plugins.Popup\Rg.Plugins.Popup\Platforms\Ios\Extensions\PlatformExtension.cs:21 
  at Rg.Plugins.Popup.IOS.Impl.PopupPlatformIos.AddAsync (Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage page) [0x00052] in Z:\Documents\OpenSource\Rg.Plugins.Popup\Rg.Plugins.Popup\Platforms\Ios\Impl\PopupPlatformIos.cs:55 
  at Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigationImpl.AddAsync (Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage page) [0x00000] in Z:\Documents\OpenSource\Rg.Plugins.Popup\Rg.Plugins.Popup\Services\PopupNavigationImpl.cs:175 
  at Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigationImpl+<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<PushAsync>b__0 () [0x00047] in Z:\Documents\OpenSource\Rg.Plugins.Popup\Rg.Plugins.Popup\Services\PopupNavigationImpl.cs:73
```

Comment: You should create your DataTemplate and assing it to the CollectionView as StaticResource. You shouldn't place UI logic on your viewmodel. Check [Xamarin Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#choose-item-appearance-at-runtime)

Comment: Thanks for the link @FabriBertani, it pointed me to the reason for the Exception. "When using CollectionView, never set the root element of your DataTemplate objects to a ViewCell. This will result in an exception being thrown because CollectionView has no concept of cells." After removing the "Cell" from the DataTemplate it loads fine. In my case there is not UI logic in involved, just a definition outside of the implementation. I need to pass a DataTemplate definition for the CollectionView into the control library form outside it.

Comment: @Sev So it is the problem about ViewCell? You solve your problem now?

Comment: It's obvious the error came from "return new ViewCell { View = grid };" when he should just use "return grid;"

Comment: How is it obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @FabriBertani for [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#choose-item-appearance-at-runtime), it pointed me to the reason for the exception.  "When using CollectionView, never set the root element of your DataTemplate objects to a ViewCell. This will result in an exception being thrown because CollectionView has no concept of cells." Having the Template's outside view be a Grid and not the unsupported Cell resolves the issue.